# Problems with installing pip on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Python 3.8.1 on my laptop. I wasn't successful in installing pip from the command prompt.

1. I opened the command prompt, went to were the file get-pip.py is located and ran the command *python get-pip.py* and nothing happened.
2. I then went to advanced systems settings/system properties/environment variables and edited the Path, put C:\Python38\scripts. I then tried again to run the command *python get-pip.py* but nothing happened

I'd appreciate any assistance, thanks

Comment: Python for Windows should come with `pip` already installed. Try `C:\Python38\bin\python -m ensurepip`

Comment: Is it called `pip3`? Also, I think `pip` ends up in the `bin` directory, not `scripts`. If you still have issues, please [edit] your question to indicate where you installed it from as particular packages of Python might have particular issues.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, pip is already installed. In fact there are three types of them, pip.exe, pip3.exe and pip3.8.exe together with easy_install.exe and easy_install-3.8.exe All these pip exe files are on the this path C:\Users\Laptopl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38.32\Scripts

Comment: @LeoBhebhe I strongly recommend using virtual environments! If pip is already installed, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful that you are actually wanting to run a specific file, hence, the directory that you are in also needs to be the right one. You can not just run the files randomly by opening cmd. First head on where your "get-pip.py" file is, then try to run the command again, and let us know the result.

Comment: I was very cautious, thanks. And I have been able to install numpy which I needed. Thanks.